# Detect if stdin is a tty device (terminal) or pipe in PHP?

Tags: php, file, stdin, pipe, tty

I wrote a php script. I want it show help message when called with standard input connected to a tty device (terminal) before reading and executing interactively, but dont show when called with a file or stream from pipe as standard input.

Is there a way to detect this from PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`posix_isatty`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php).

This function accepts both a file descriptor (an integer) and a PHP stream. If it receives a PHP stream, it automatically attempts to [cast it](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/README.STREAMS?pathrev=296679&view=markup#l166) in order to obtain a file descriptor and use it instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 7.2 you can use [`stream_isatty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-isatty.php), which works on Windows too.

For example:

```
php -r "var_dump(stream_isatty(STDERR));"
```

Results in

```
bool(true)
```

But

```
php -r "var_dump(stream_isatty(STDERR));" 2>output.txt
```

Results in

```
bool(false)
```

(this of course works on STDOUT too).